# In PyCharm, how to navigate to the top of the file?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm new to PyCharm and haven't been able to figure out what I'm sure is a very simple thing -- what's the key stroke to go to the top of the current file?

(Bonus question -- is there a way to scroll to the top of the current file without moving the cursor there also, a la the Home key in Sublime Text 2?)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/689623/pycharm-how-to-jump-to-top-or-bottom-of-script-with-keyboard-shortcuts too

Comment: I voted to re-open this question since PyCharm is a software tool which is primarily for programming.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You navigate to the top of the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>. It moves cursor too. So does navigating via <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Page Down</kbd> keys.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> move the view without moving cursor but scrolling the long file takes some time.

Additionally You can change the keymap (Settings > Keymap). There is 'Scroll to Top' in 'Editor Actions'. You can use Your own key binding for this action, by default (in PyCharm 4 and later) it is not set.

Comment: Super, thanks. (For OS X users out there, it's Cmd-Home.) And super re: the scroll to top action. I realize the reason I didn't find it was that I didn't have the non-menu actions checkbox selected in the Cmd-A find action popup (it's off by default), so it wasn't showing these scroll and move to top actions, making me think they might not exist.

Comment: To clarify, for Mac, it is <kbd>Cmd+fn+left</kbd> - the action is called Move Caret to Text Start :/

Comment: If you don't have a home or end key on your Mac keyboard, try `fn+ up arrow` or `fn+ down arrow`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In mac, `Command` + `Home` will go to the top of file

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to navigate to the first line using goto line: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>1</kbd>. But this will move the cursor to the first line.

A small disadvantage is it is a two step process and adds a navigation step. Moving back to your previous location with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd><</kbd> will have to be done in two steps if you do an edit.